# I'm having trouble with the sort order in a kbmmemtable

Tags: sorting, delphi, indexing

I have a Delphi 10.1 Berlin application that is using a kbmMemTable 7.82 table.  It is indexed on two fields: lastname and firstname.

My problem is that the order is wrong when an apostrophe is encountered.  It may also happen with other characters, but I haven't tested it extensively.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried it on both Delphi 7 and Delphi 10.1 Berlin and get the same results.  I've tried having the index be case-sensitive and case-insensitive.  In all four cases, I get the same results.  I've also tried creating the index programmatically and through the object inspector.

Here is the generic form of how I created the index programatically:

```
    Table.Open;
    IndexDef := Table.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef;
    IndexDef.Name := IndexByName;
    IndexDef.Fields := 'lastname;firstname';
    IndexDef.Options := [ixCaseInsensitive];
    Table.Indexes.Add(IndexDef);
    Table.IndexName := IndexByName;
    Table.IndexFieldNames := 'lastname;firstname';
    Table.CreateIndexes;
    Table.EnableIndexes := True;
    Table.First;
```

The index puts O'HARA after OLSON, instead of before.  This works the same with and without case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the locale settings defines the order.
Try to set mtifoIgnoreLocale in the index definition, alternatively setup a locale that provides the correct sort order.

Then it will do a simple sort.

best regards
Kim/C4D

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for the quick response.  I assumed that the locale would be set to the default Windows locale for the system it's running on.  I couldn't figure out how to set mtifoIgnoreLocale in the index definition as you suggested.  I then tried setting the locale to 1033 (US English) on the table at design time, and when that didn't work, I tried it at run time, but it still didn't work.  Finally, I found the ":L" field modifier, and that worked.  Thank you for your help.